# Nuxt3 useAsyncData not working onMounted lifecycle hook

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm still a bit confused on what I'm doing wrong here. Essentially I have a vue component in which I want to load some data in async after element is mounted.

I'm using NUXT 3 and composition API.

```
<script setup>

let directories = useState('directories', () => null);

onMounted( async () => {
const { data: response } = await useAsyncData('directories', () => $fetch('/api/s3-get-directories'));
directories.value = response;
});

</script>
```

It seems like onMounted triggers before render and is not receiving data correctly. If I wrap on mounted into setTimeout and give 100ms delay it works fine.

I would appreciate an example of how I should load in data without blocking after client is ready. Or any explanation on what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: why are you using useAsyncData inside onMounted hook it's kind of strange if you want get data in client side you can just fetch that data inside onMounted without asyncData or if you really need it you can just call it with `server:false` option

Comment: So why is it not working? I have the same question

Comment: @MaxFlex `onMounted` is a life-cycle hook. `asyncData` is too. Mixing those 2 is counter-intuitive and makes no sense. It's like calling a `beforeMount` and `updated` [in Vue](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/lifecycle.html#lifecycle-diagram), makes no sense use one or the other.

Comment: @kissu Konstantin, thanks for the response. Is `useFetch` a life-cycle hook too? I'm having this issue with `useFetch`, I just want to load data `onMounted` – which seems totally intuitive

Comment: @MaxFlex hm, it's maybe not exactly a lifecycle actually but still behaving not like people think it is. Check this video from Alex Lichter to see how to use it properly: https://youtu.be/njsGVmcWviY?si=S-ShGN8mRTLz0wK8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing `{ server: false }` in options

```js
await useLazyAsyncData('directories', () => $fetch('/api/s3-get-directories'), { server: false });
```

This makes it only run in front-end and not back-end.

Comment: if you need prerender data and SEO , it's totally wrong and your data will fetch in client side it's almost equal to fetch data in onMounted

Comment: @zia can you give the solution on how to do it properly? I have been stuck with this problem too.

Comment: ‍‍```const { pending, data }=await useLazyAsyncData('directories', () => $fetch('/api/s3-get-directories')); ```

you should not pass server:false if you need prerender and seo