# Nuxt3: How do I use useFetch() in onMounted()?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

This code does not work reactivity.

It is a hassle to copy the return value of `useFetch()`.

How can I somehow use the Destructuring assignment syntax to enable reactivity?

```html
<script lang="ts" setup>
    const a = ref<boolean>(false)
    const b = ref<FetchError|null>()
    const c = ref<any[]>([])

    onMounted(async () => {
        const { pending: a, error: b, data: c} = toRefs(
            await useLazyFetch<any[]>(
            "http://localhost:3178/posts"
            )
        )
    })
</script>
<template>
    <div>{{ a }}</div>
    <div>{{ b }}</div>
    <div>{{ c }}</div>
</template>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be caused by that you use it the wrong way. Vue composables are intended to be used directly in setup block, any other exception needs to be confirmed. `await useLazyFetch` is a mistake, it doesn't return a promise, this isn't how composables work, with useFetch (not useLazyFetch) being an exception for this rule. So you just call useLazyFetch in setup, and it's supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70464990/nuxt3-useasyncdata-not-working-onmounted-lifecycle-hook)
I hope that that will be helpful.

It worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).